# Firebase Firestore query with related document references

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to model "memberships" with Firestore. The idea is that there are companies, users and then memberships.

The memberships collection stores a reference to a company and to a user, as well as a role as a string, e..g admin or editor.

How would I query to get the users with a certain role for a company?

This is what I currently have with some basic logging.

```
const currentCompanyID = 'someid';

return database
.collection('memberships')
.where('company', '==', database.doc(`companies/${currentCompanyID}`))
.where('role', '==', 'admin')
.get()
.then(snap => {
  snap.forEach(function(doc) {
    console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
    const data = doc.data();
    console.log(data.user.get());
  });
})
.catch(error => {
  console.error('Error fetching documents: ', error);
});
```

`data.user.get()` returns a promise to the user, but I'd have to do that for every user which seems inefficient?

What would be the best way to approach this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cloud Firestore deep get with subcollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46611279/cloud-firestore-deep-get-with-subcollection)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is close to what you want, but there are two issues:

- Your `where()` clause can't compare a field with a document reference, because Firestore is a classic [denormalized datastore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization). There aren't ways to strongly guarantee that one document refers to another. You'll need to store document IDs and maintain consistency yourself. (Example below).
- Queries actually return a QuerySnapshot, which includes all the docs that result from a query. So you're not getting one document at a time — you'll get all the ones that match. (See code below)

So a corrected version that fits the spirit of what you want:

```
const currentCompanyID = '8675309';
const querySnapshot = await database
  .collection('memberships')
  .where('companyId', '==', currentCompanyID)
  .where('role', '==', 'admin')
  .get();  // <-- this promise, when awaited, pulls all matching docs

await Promise.all(querySnapshot.map(async snap => {
  const data = doc.data();
  const user = await database
    .collection('users')
    .doc(data.userId)
    .get();

  console.log(doc.id, ' => ', data);
  console.log(user);
});
```

There isn't a faster way on the client side to fetch all the users that your query refers to at once -- it's part of the trouble of trying to use a denormalized store for queries that feel much more like classic relational database queries.

If this ends up being a query you run often (i.e. get users with a certain role within a specific company), you could consider storing membership information as part of the `user` doc instead. That way, you could query the `users` collection and get all the matching users in one shot.