# Return document and subCollection data in Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function that gets all the documents where an id matches like so:

```
const query = admin.firestore().collection('unassignedItems').doc('1uD82gAXORYsyimX5Dw23DDAimx1').collection('unassigned')
    .where('meta.designId', "==", id);

const qs = await query.get();
const items = [];

qs.forEach(doc => {
    items.push(doc.data());
});
return items;
```

The documents that are returned though all have a subCollection called images, that contains a document containing more information.

Is there a way I can return this information along with the parent document information at the same time from my function?

Answer (score 2):

Since Cloud Firestore queries are shallow and don't touch subcollections, you will need to query each subcollection individually, in addition to the query you're making for the documents in `unassignedItems/{id}/unassigned`.

See also:

- [Firestore get all docs and subcollections of root collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46875966/firestore-get-all-docs-and-subcollections-of-root-collection?rq=1)
- [Cloud Firestore deep get with subcollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46611279/cloud-firestore-deep-get-with-subcollection)